# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (Trying to change PDF file to CSV File)

Tags: python, directory, spyder, file-not-found, tabula

I am a new python learner. I am trying to change the PDF file to CSV file by using Spyder. However, I cannot run the code as the systems tell me no such file and directory. How can I solve this problem?

Input

```
import tabula
dfs = tabula.read_pdf("RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf", pages='all')


tabula.convert_into("RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')


tabula.convert_into_by_batch("input_directory", output_format='csv', pages='all')
```

Output

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf'
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Please show the directory structure of your project, including where the entrypoint to your code is and where the file "RN(G)-GazetteList.pdf" is located.

Comment: hello Neil, my file is C:\Users\home\Desktop\RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf and my entry point of the code is "import Tabula" I have tried to change my code `import tabula
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\home\Desktop\RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf', pages='all')


tabula.convert_into(r'\C:\Users\home\Desktop\RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf', "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')

tabula.convert_into_by_batch("input_directory", output_format='csv', pages='all')`

Comment: No man. What is the name of the Python file that you run when you run your program, and where is that located?

Comment: Your edited comment says the file is called "RN(G)-GazetteList.pdf.pdf" but in your question you are trying to open "RN(G)-GazetteList.pdf". Please confirm which is correct.

Comment: My python file name is Temporary file and it located at C:\Users\home\.spyder-py3\temp.py

Comment: RN(G)-GazetteList.pdf.pdf this one is correct one

Comment: Now, the output is `runfile('C:/Users/home/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/home/.spyder-py3')`

Comment: Okay so the file you are trying to read is not in the same place as the Python file that you are running. So Python won't know where to find it. Opening files from random places on your computer is tricky in general and you should either avoid this, or use os.path to help prevent typos and other mistakes. Have you tried using the absolute path with the correct filename? Is there a reason that you can't keep the file in the same directory as the Python file?

Comment: I don't know. But it sounds like the original problem is solved.

Comment: so is it mean that i can run the code successfully with this output 'runfile('C:/Users/home/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/home/.spyder-py3')'? But it seems that I still cannot get the CSV file, do u know what's the problem of my code ?

Comment: On Stackoverflow, when you encounter a new problem, you should open a new question.